# How to Properly make Typescript based Create React App target ES3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, user-interface

I'm learning how to make react based web pages.
And after I've got to know that typescript can transpile to ES3 which is basically supported on all browsers.
 i started trying to make a simple Hello World React app that would use ES3 JavaScript, which i tested on an IE8 of a virtual machine Win7.
 but the thing is... to probably no one's surprise it did not work.

---

### Here are the measures i took to configure my app:

1. At First I only changed `tsconfig.json`'s { "target" : "es3" }

- the results were a bunch of errors on `npm start`

2. so i added { "lib" : [`...` , "ES5", "ES6"] } (I added more `ES#` at first but it somehow gave more errors)

- and the development server started successfully
- but when i tried opening it in IE8 it gave an error that it didn't recognize `=>` which is understandable

3. so i started searching for why is JavaScript Not transpiled correctly to ES3, and tried returning back to { "target" : "ES5" } ,  which shouldn't support arrow functions either.

- but they still existed in the final code

4. so i tried building it instead, and i used `npm run build`

- which did solve that problem, but the code now contained `Symbol`s which gave errors on IE8.

5. so i just started trying random actions like adding the `{ "downlevelIteration": true, "importHelpers": true }`, and `tsc .`

- which of course didn't work.

6. then i found in a random website that i can add a `./src/tsconfig.json` and a `./src/tsconfig.dev.json`, so i configured the `target` `downlevelIteration` and `importhelpers` and built the webpage.

- well it didn't work, same problem.

7. i started to get agitated, so i imported `react-app-polyfill` and `babel-polyfill` and built.

- This Time although the final JavaScript file didn't contain `Symbol`, it did't work because of some dumb error that expected some `string` in some line that goes: `name-idont-remember : function(){function i dont remember}`. so understandably i Stopped My Self From Punching The Computer Having Wasted About 4/5 days with this problematic objective...

8. **after "some" searching** i think that, that code is needed to be `ES3ify`ed, because i see a resemblance between the forgotten line, and a line that was given in a `ES3ify` Example, where a line like that was converted to  `"name-idont-remember" : function(){function i dont remember}` i think.

---

### ** EDIT: i Would Also Use VITE if it's easier. **

**So Now all I Ask For is some Kind of Guideline/List of Steps,
that i would take every time i want to make a ES3 React-App.**

*if you can Provide This Kind Of TODO List, or you have link to something like that which is clear, i would appreciate that act of kindness every time i stop myself from creating a beautiful Hole In the Screen of My Computer 
( I would Appreciate it **a lot** )*

**so i would also appreciate it if you gave me guidance on where i went wrong, or even better, what was wrong with every step i took.**

thank you people/(and AIs now too i guess) a lot.

Comment: ES3 is deprecated since 2009, every browser is supporting at least ES6 now. I doubt anything can compile to ES3 now

Comment: Internet explorer is dead btw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/internet-explorer-11-end-of-support

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that `ES3`, is Mostly **Dead/Deprecated**, But i insist on the _Importance of transpiling My webpage to_ `ES3`. **thanks for the insight though**, i appreciate the fact that you **didn't assume i know,** because although I've come across this one information throughout my lengthy search for answers, i probably didn't come across a lot other stuff.

Comment: i would also would like to add that i know of the fact that **it is Possible to build react-apps that support** `ES3`. so if you have confirmed knowledge of the Opposite, please inform me of the updates. with appreciation.

Comment: Your dependencies don't get transpiled by typescript, so the issue is probably in your build, not specifically typescript.

Comment: The easiest answer is probably looking for dependency versions that are more ancient but of course this has its own issues.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is true or not, but what i think is stooping me now is actually `es3ify` which i don't know how to integrate as a loader in my `npx create-react-app app-name --template typescript` because when, built IE8 give the `expected identifier, string or number` error where `return {default : something}` which should be `"default"` and same thing with `delete/catch` so i need to use `es3ify` but I'm not sure how. if someone can show me how to `es3ify` my bundled react app, i will be thankful.

Comment: I understand that ES3 may be important still to *you*, but that is untrue for the vast majority of the community (including tool and lib authors). So the more tools/libs in your stack, the less likely a transpilation to ES3 is going to be. *Something* is going to be broken, and I get that is really frustrating if your stuck in a situation where you have to support dead technology. But the truth is simply that you are going to have to excise parts of the stack, pin to old versions and hope they're still available, etc. I strongly recommend committing your node_modules if you get it working.

Comment: But seriously, if you are "I'm learning how to make react based web pages" you aren't going to be able to accomplish this. This is a (possibly impossible) task for an expert in JS tooling with lots of experience in tweaking things for IE compatibility (if you can find one who's interested, I'm sure not). If you are in a position where your employer requires you to support archaic tech then you will not be able to use the latest/greatest tools, frameworks, and libraries. Stick as close to vanilla as you possibly can and tell the business that velocity and ability to hire will suffer greatly.

Answer (score 1):

**babel.config.js:**

module.exports = function(api) {
const isProd = api.env('production');

```
// ES3 configuration
const es3 = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: false,
                corejs: 3,
                
                debug: false /* set to true, to see the included polyfills, warning large output */
            }
        ]
    ],
    plugins: [
        'transform-es5-property-mutators',
        'transform-es2015-arrow-functions'
    ]
};

return {
    
    // other configurations possible
    env: {
        es3
    },
    presets: [],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
    ignore: ['node_modules'],
    sourceMaps: true,
    compact: isProd
};
```

};

**vite.config.js:**

```
        plugins: [
            
            ...
            babel({
                babelHelpers: 'bundled',
                envName: 'es3'
            }),
            ...
```

Have only tested it in a javascript project so far.
I still need to convert everything to Typescript before I can say for sure that it will work there.

I still need to verify the finished build, but won't get to it until Friday. The Vite build process itself is working fine at the moment.

Eslint Compat also shows no problems that it would not be ES3 compatible.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-legacy possible that plugin can help you too ;-)